# Angular - Model not updating on Datetimepicker update event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Given the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/w3L2y4xj/3/

When I click on the input section and update the value of the date the model changes. However when I click on the calendar icon (at the right of the textbox) and change the date in the resulting calendar picker boxes, the value of the model does not change.

How can I get the model value to change when the calendar is clicked?

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepickerbox'>
  <input datetimepicker class="form-control" ng-model = "day" callback-fn="ctrlFnDate(datetype)"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
```

The following directive is responsible for updating the model value.

```
myApp.directive('datetimepicker', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

      element.datetimepicker({});
      element.on('dp.change', function(event) { 
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(event.date.format());
        });
      })
    }
  } 
});
```

Is there any way to make the calendar icon work?

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein When you click on the calendar (one from the icon) and change the date does the text below the input change value?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. I've put in an edit to clarify your problem.

Comment: The example seems to be doing the behavior you're expecting. What browser are you using to test?

Comment: @kand Chrome, most recent version